# Adding delay over keyup or keydown event in #EmberJs textbox

Tags: jquery, ember.js, underscore.js

Please look at this [fiddle](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EBoLEZe/1/edit). It shows how to add a textbox and then add a key-down event to it using emberjs. And in the event handler, it prints the value present in the textbox.

What I want to do is - Add some delay. So instead of showing the value in the textbox immediately system should wait for specified time and then it should fire the event.

Something like `_.debounce()` from underscore.js library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember provides its own debounce method in run package.

this is the bin link http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EBoLEZe/35/edit

Docs link http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_debounce

I have a blog post on same http://blog.adisrikanth.com/68

BTW make sure pass name of the function rather anonymous one inside debounce.